# SmartStoreSDKManager returns RuntimeException

Tags: android, salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am trying to use smartStore in native android using Salesforce sdk development.

I have followed the Salesforce doc, and whenever i want to get the instance of SmartStoreSDKManager using

```
SmartStoreSDKManager sdkManager = SmartStoreSDKManager.getInstance();
```

My app crashes with exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.audi.audidrive, PID: 21152
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.audi.audidrive/com.audi.audidrive.activities.ClaimActivity}
:java.lang.ClassCastException: com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.SalesforceSDKManager cannot be cast to com.salesforce.androidsdk.smartstore.app.SmartStoreSDKManager
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.SalesforceSDKManager cannot be cast to com.salesforce.androidsdk.smartstore.app.SmartStoreSDKManager
 atcom.salesforce.androidsdk.smartstore.app.SmartStoreSDKManager.getInstance(SmartStoreSDKManager.java:132)
at com.audi.audidrive.activities.ClaimActivity.onCreate(ClaimActivity.java:88)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Can someone help me to use smartStore in native android? any source code to use ?
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

What you have to do is change the initialization of the SDK Manager.
Basically, in your application changes

```
SalesForceSDKManager.initNative
```

for

```
SmartStoreSDKManager.initNative
```